# First Order Logic Statement for Proof. Manipulating Quantifiers

Tags: prolog, logic, quantifiers, first-order-logic

Ok, I have the given relation:
If F(x) is not true then no case satisfies G(x) and H(y,x).
((∀x ¬F(x)) ⇒¬(∀y G(y) ˄ H(y,x)))

Now, Can I possibly convert this into:
(∀y G(y) ˄ H(y,x))) ⇒ ((∀x F(x))  ????

If not, the left hand side essentially has to imply:
If F(x) is not true.... Mentions nothing about the For All or Existential Quantifiers. Can I take the negation outside of the Quantifier i.e. put it as (¬(∀x F(x)), because this makes the job much easier???

Comment: A proper place to ask this question is http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the right place but, no you can't. 
Moving the negation out would change the quantifier. Also, the initial formula may not be what you want: the last x is a free variable.

Comment: I see, what if this was the statement now?(∀x ¬F(x)) ⇒¬(∃ y G(y)) ˄ H(y,x))? Sorry, I made an error before...

Comment: All you need here is two basic equivalences. Apologies for the notation:

 (1) ∀x ¬F = ¬ ∃x F

 (2) F ⇒ G = ¬ F v G.

You can easily find out the answer by yourself :)